Retry deferred probe at runtime (device tree)
I've developed a device tree overlay to describe some pieces of my embedded system.  The system is comprised of a Raspberry Pi, a separate custom circuit board with a few I2C devices, and a power supply.  While the Raspberry Pi gets power all the time, the separate circuit board only gets power when it's enabled externally.  Now, if the separate circuit board is powered when the Pi boots, the device tree overlay works flawlessly, and all I2C devices on the separate circuit board work properly.  However, if the Pi boots before the separate circuit board is powered, the kernel log shows
[   17.630787] i2c 1-0040: deferred probe pending

and obviously I cannot communicate with the I2C devices.
Now, if I remove the dtoverlay from /boot/firmware/config.txt and try to load the overlay dynamically at runtime (after the circuit board has power), one of the drivers fails to load with the following messages in dmesg:
[   43.227575] tps25990 1-0040: Found fault-gpio
[   43.227586] tps25990 1-0040: Found fault-gpio at gpio586
[   43.227593] tps25990 1-0040: fault-gpio is mapped to IRQ-6
[   43.227598] tps25990 1-0040: irq_set_irq_type returns -22
[   43.227604] tps25990 1-0040: Failed to request fault-gpio irq (code: -22)
[   43.227615] tps25990: probe of 1-0040 failed with error -22

For reference, here's the relevant lines of code from the driver:
    data->fault_gpio  = devm_gpiod_get_optional(&client->dev, "fault", GPIOD_IN);
    if (data->fault_gpio) {
        dev_info(&client->dev, "Found fault-gpio at gpio%d\n", desc_to_gpio(data->fault_gpio));
        gpiod_set_consumer_name(data->fault_gpio, "EFUSE FAULT");
        data->fault_gpio_irq = gpiod_to_irq(data->fault_gpio);
        if (data->fault_gpio_irq < 0) {
            dev_err(&client->dev, "No corresponding irq for fault-gpio\n");
            return data->fault_gpio_irq;
        } else {
            dev_info(&client->dev, "fault-gpio is mapped to IRQ%d\n", data->fault_gpio_irq);
        }
        ret = irq_set_irq_type(data->fault_gpio_irq, IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_FALLING);
        dev_dbg(&client->dev, "irq_set_irq_type returns %d\n", ret);
        ret = devm_request_threaded_irq(&client->dev,
                data->fault_gpio_irq,
                NULL,
                efuse_fault_gpio_irq_handler,
                0,
                "efuse fault",
                data);
        if (ret) {
            dev_err(&client->dev, "Failed to request fault-gpio irq (code: %d)\n", ret);
            irq_dispose_mapping(data->fault_gpio_irq);
            return ret;
        }
    } else {
        dev_info(&client->dev, "No fault-gpio found in device tree\n");
    }

So it appears that irq_set_irq_type fails when loading the dtoverlay dynamically.  Does anyone have suggestions on how to correct this?  I'd prefer to just have the overlay loaded at boot and just keep retrying, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

First of all, read the contents of the /sys/kernel/debug/devices_deferred (IIRC the name of the file), it will show the reason why it was deferred. It may give a clue. Second, what are you trying to achieve with the irq_set_irq_type() call? Do oyu have broken DT to begin with? Why can't you fix it properly? Third, what the purpose of irq_dispose_mapping()?

@0andriy, I understand why it's deferred (the board doesn't have power). The driver is for an I2C electronic fuse which also has a fault pin which I've tied to GPIO.  It's actually tied to a GPIO expander on the same circuit board, which is also described in the same device tree overlay; the GPIO expander also does not have power at boot.  When the board has power at boot, all of this works perfectly.  When I remove the overlay from config.txt and try to load it dynamically, it fails.  Is it possible that the GPIO expander driver loads in the wrong order when the overlay is loaded dynamically?

@0andriy, I've gone ahead and removed the GPIO from the driver.  I can handle that using libgpiod if necessary.  Now I can dynamically load the driver successfully.  However, I'm still curious if there's a way to force a "re-probe" of a device that's flagged as "deferred probe" without rebooting.  Is there any mechanism to do that?

Yes, it’s done automatically on each new device driver binding attempt. Again, you most likely put incorrect settings for the GPIO.

Ah, you mean that you have broken hardware design? If you have chicken/egg issues on hardware, it’s unlikely to be solved in software.

@0andriy you say "on each new driver binding attempt"; is there a way to re-attempt driver binding? And yes this is a chicken/egg problem. I just didn't realize that there would be no way to remedy it without rebooting. I want the power to the separate board to be controlled in software, but the board needs to be powered for the driver to load. I didn't think that this would be a fringe use case. I guess that's what I get for trying to do any of this at the kernel level.

@0andriy, I managed to solve my issue by forcing a "re-probe" of the GPIO expander driver echo 1-0074 | sudo tee /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/pca953x/bind which triggers the deferred probe of the tps25990 driver.

It’s not a solution, when resources are not available, but described in DT code that provides it has to return deferred probe, and when resource becomes available the reprobing is triggered automatically.
